# How to return some data from a function nested in another, using Async and Await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, return-value

I have the following piece of code: an endpoint getting the URL of an image, downloading it, resize it, saving it locally, then uploading it to a S3 bucket. Every piece of code works fine on it's own.

```
// Post a URL of a pic and get a URL of its thumb on AWS S3
router.post("/", (req, res) => {

  const url = req.body.url;
  const tempPath = './public/uploads/';
  const tempFileName = uuidv1();

  const createThumbPic = async () => {
    const tempURL = tempPath + tempFileName;
    jimp.read(url, async (err, img) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
          error: `${err})`,
        });
        return;
      }
      img.resize(120, 120)
        .quality(60)
        .write(tempURL);
    });
    return tempURL;
  }

  const uploadThumbnailToS3 = async () => {
    const tempURLThumb = await createThumbPic();
    const file = await fs.readFileSync(tempURLThumb);
    const params = {
      Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_ID,
      Key: tempFileName,
      Body: file
    };
    // Uploading files to the bucket
    const fileUrlOns3 = await s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: err });
      }
      res.status(201).json({ thumbUrl: resData });
      return data.Location;
    });
    return fileUrlOns3;
  }

  // Execute Code and respond to client
  uploadThumbnailToS3().catch((err) => {
    res.status(400).json({ error: err });
  });

});
```

the Error I am getting back from this endpoint:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errno": -2,
        "syscall": "open",
        "code": "ENOENT",
        "path": "./public/uploads/imagefiletemp.jpg"
    }
}
```

The problem comes from the follwing to lines: It seems that `fs.readFileSync`runs before that `createThumbPic()` is totally finished. Hence that the readFileSync doesn't find the file it should read, and throw that error back.

```
const tempURLThumb = await createThumbPic();
const file = await fs.readFileSync(tempURLThumb);
```

Somehow I know that `createThumbPic` return `tempURLThumb` before that the fiel is finished, as I get the response in postman, than 1 sec later I see the file appearing in my directory.

```
const createThumbPic = async () => {
    const tempURL = tempPath + tempFileName;
    jimp.read(url, async (err, img) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
          error: `${err})`,
        });
        return;
      }
      img.resize(120, 120)
        .quality(60)
        .write(tempURL);
    });
    return tempURL;
  }
```

How to make `createThumbPic`wait until `img.resize` is completely finished before returning tempURL?

I tried my best learning ASYNC/AWAIT, and thought I had figured, but it seems like something is still off in my code. Any tip?

Comment: that is because you declared `uploadFileS3` as `async`. Under the hood, js will create a promise and then you should use `await` as Aaron pointed out

Comment: I added a second duplicate question that explains your updated problem.

Comment: Regarding your update: `createThumbPic` does not wait for `jimp.read` to complete before it returns. You might want to read [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises).

Comment: Don't pass callbacks to something that you expect to get a promise from, both the `jimp.read` and `s3.upload` calls.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` your promise:

```
        // upload to S3
        const thumbOnS3 = await uploadFileS3(tempURL, tempFileName);
        console.log(thumbOnS3)
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but If I add await, I get `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`, because jimp.read is not async.

Comment: or uploadFileS3(tempURL, tempFileName).then(thumbOnS3 => console.log(thumbOnS3);